# 2 or 3 Categorys search checkbox php

Tags: php, mysql, search, checkbox

Each Article can have unlimited categories.
Categories are saved in the database like this
example `article_category: '1','3','8'`
OR
example `article_category: '2','3'`
So when I search for a listing under, lets say category 3

```
$category_id = '1,3';

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE article_category = '$category_id'";
```

If it were just one the above would work fine.
I hate to say it but I'm completely lost.. Would I use `IN` ?

Comment: use IN sql operator if you want multipal id's to check against the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE article_category IN (".$category_id.")";
```

Comment: not working because article_category === $category_id with IN. but article_category = '1','3','8'    $category_id= '1,3'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ARTICLES 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET($category_id, article_category) > 0
```

Comment: No view steambuy.com/catalogue.php?q= sidebar left Популярные жанры under checkbox type search jquery

Comment: @SeymurHaşımov category is stored in what format in DB? article_category = 1,3,8 OR article_category = '1','3','8'

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_in_set()`;

```
 $SQL= "SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1,article_category)>0";
```

Comment: No view http://steambuy.com/catalogue.php?q=     sidebar left Популярные жанры under checkbox type search jquery

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem then you want to make query for different categories at a time.

If I am correct then to do so you will have to get the categories type in an array or diifferent variables then compare each one of them in the where clause using or.
Like: where article_category='$x1' or article_category='$x2' or... so on.

Comment: No view steambuy.com/catalogue.php?q= sidebar left Популярные жанры under checkbox type search jquery